# Bluetooth Thermal Printer print GBP £ symbol

Tags: android, escpos

Which is the right way to print GB pound symbol in thermal printer?

I am using the following code for writing printer:

```
String pound = "\u00a3";
opstream = BluetoothPrinter.btSocket.getOutputStream();

//Tried
outputStream.write(pound.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

//Tried
outputStream.write(pound.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

I have tried like **£** also. What is the alternative for this in a thermal printer?

Comment: I tried to set static symbol like: `String pound = "£";`. it's working my thermal printer. Please set static symbol and check it.

Comment: I tried that too that I mentioned in my question also

Comment: Also try to this byte `c2 a3` for symbol

Comment: c2 a3 How to use this? Replace currency with this ?

Comment: yes, String pound = "c2 a3".

Comment: It's also not working just print as c2 a3. Tried now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192713/discussion-between-nikunj-sorathiya-and-amsheer).

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed `00` `A3` eg. in [code-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) `1252` or `437`.

To switch, that's `ESC t n` where `n` equals `16` eg. for code-page `1252`.

> Select character code table.

```
  ASCII  ESC   t   n
   Hex.  1B   74  0F
Decimal  27  116  16
```

This should encode it into a matching format:

```
String gbp = "£";
byte[] b = gbp.getBytes(Charset.forName("Windows-1252"));
```

The output `b` should in every case be `00` `A3` and *the printer needs to know which code-page it is*. Unless the printer won't be switched to a code-page which has the `£`, it won't print a `£`, no matter which value it is being represented by (except as graphics). See the [ESC/POS Mode Command Specifications](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/mannualfolder/escpos_cm_en.pdf), page 4-47. In unicode it's also [U+00A3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm) (which the printer likely won't support).

The whole sequence would be: `1B 74 0F` `00 A3`

and to switch back to default code-page: `1B 74 00`

---

**Consult your printer's manual**, which code-pages it even supports (also the `0F` might vary).

Comment: I think I am not understanding your answer String gbp = "£";
byte[] b = gbp.getBytes(Charset.forName("Windows-1252")); Is the above code is enough? Because that one I already tried and not working.

Comment: @Amsheer my answer clearly states that you have to switch to a code-page which has the `£`... else the printer will not understand the input and might interpret it as something else. Just see the appendix of the printer's manual, where you can find the `£` symbol (they always come with code-page charts).

Comment: @Amsheer the default code-page might not have a `£`. just see my answer.

Comment: Your answer maybe perfect but my problem is I am not able to understand what is in that table from wikipedia. For replacing £ which code I need to use. Please help

Comment: code-page [437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set) also has it, but it depends what the default code-page of the printer is - and how to switch it... because it only prints when the charset of the `byte[]` & the current code-page of the printer match.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to this:

```
String pound = "£ 20.00";
outputStream.write(BitmapAsEuro(pound));

public byte[] BitmapAsEuro(String poundValue){
        Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(600, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setTextSize(26);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(26);
        paint.setFlags(Paint.EMBEDDED_BITMAP_TEXT_FLAG);

        canvas.drawText(poundValue,0,60,paint);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        image.recycle();
        return byteArray;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**I found this**

String pound = "€";

String codeL = "GBK";

opstream = BluetoothPrinter.btSocket.getOutputStream();

outputStream.write(pound.getBytes(codeL));

Comment: Where did you find this? How does it improve the existing answers? Please clarify.

Comment: I came to this solution by reading this and works with most of the thermal printers 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding)